# Why I'm getting the installation menu again after installing?

Tags: system-installation

After I choose to reboot the computer when ubuntu 13.10 done installing, I booted again with the "Try Ubuntu" or "Install now"

I chose install now (note that I installed ubuntu already) and it had 3 options:

- Reinstall windows and install ubuntu or something like that
- Reinstall ubuntu
- And format everything and install ubuntu again

I chose back, and I chose the "try ubuntu"

Is this normal? All my system is functioning ok right? I have every feature like a normal ubuntu user cause I installed it right??

Comment: did you ejected the installation disk after the install was completed (before reboot)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to eject the cd and reboot the system. But everything is normal.

Answer (score 1):

The installation should have told you that you should Eject/Unplug your CD/DVD/USB so you can boot normally. Just remove the drive and you will be OK and booting Ubuntu from the Hard Disk.